# JQuery Delegate doesn't work with 'click'

Tags: jquery

Everything is in the title :

I am appening some html content to a html page in response to an ajax call.

My `'Click'` delegate doesn't work but the `'mouseenter'` delegate works fine. Why the 'click' doesn't work ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('mouseenter', '.fb-usr-account a', function (e) {
        console.log('enter');
    });
    $(this).on('click', '.fb-usr-account a', function (e) {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});
```

UPDATE :
No `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` anywhere

Comment: If there's any event handler that stops the click propagation then the delegate won't fire.

Comment: Delegate to a parent html element such as the `body` rather than the `document`. Eg: `$("body").on('click', '.fb-usr-account a',...`

Comment: Yeah, but i am not doing any `event.stopPropagation` or any `event.preventDefault`. I've updated the question with this info

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois What about `return false;`?  Something somewhere is stopping click event propagation. Now you could still capture it but... `this.addEventListener('click', function(e){if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a" && $(e.target).parents('.fb-usr-account').length) console.log('clicked');}, true);`  As a side note, your `ready` handler is useless here

Comment: Yes it is useless since here is just the part of the code revelent to the question. Thanks, I will check for propagation but since i am the only one working on this code i don't think so.

Comment: Just to edit previous comment, this would be more appropriate: `this.addEventListener('click', function(e){if($(e.target).closest('.fb-usr-account a').length) console.log('clicked');}, true);`. You should test it, if it works, then the issue is regarding event propagation. If it doesn't, then something else disables the possibility to click element, maybe some kind of animation/css behaviour. Anyway, when asking this kind of question, you have to provide a MCVE

Comment: @A.Wolff I was led to believe that jQuery's `.on` requires an actual element to attach the listener to rather than the entire document. In my testing however, this is not the case. Although it is still good practice (and more efficient) to delegate to the closest static parent.

Comment: @A.Wolff You were right, the main js of the page is doing a `return false`, since I can't change it I will go with your solution. Thank you for you reply.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois Just be aware of capturing event phase support;, IE8 doesn't support it e.g